# Violation of Software Principle

Tags: software-design

I was reading about threads and it was mentioned that by implementing the Runnable interface, we are violating  the principle that each object should have a single, clearly-defined responsibility. Can someone explain how is it that it violate the software principle ?

Comment: As you quote, it does not make sense. Can you provide the link to the text you were reading?

Comment: The book I am reading is Introduction to Programming Using Java, by David J Eck. Here is the text where it is mentioned "That run()
method has access to everything in the class, including private variables and methods. The
disadvantage is that this way of doing things is not very object-oriented: It violates the principle
that each object should have a single, clearly-defined responsibility. Instead of making some
random object Runnable just so that you can use it to make a thread, you can consider using
a nested inner subclass of the Thread class to define the thread. (See Subsection 5.7.2.)"

Comment: Implementing a Runnable interface is like to implement a leak to the class's "guts". You might take into consideration the Law of Demeter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Try to think how simple and strict are those principles, and how it promotes a tidy modelling.

Answer (score 1):

The principle comes from object-oriented modeling community. For example, in OO modeling, if class "A" extends lass "B", then the sentence "A is a kind of B" should make some kind of sense. Maybe the analog for class "A" implements interface "C" is "A is capable of doing C"?

Let's look at some examples:

```
public class Mammal extends Animal
```

This example reads well: **A mammal is a kind of animal.**

Now let's add some interfaces:

```
public class Mammal extends Animal implements Walking, Carnivorous
```

Everything is still good: **A mammal is a kind of animal that is capable of walking and eating meat.**

Now let's add Runnable:

```
public class Mammal extends Animal implements Walking, Carnivorous, Runnable
```

Read it: **A mammal is an animal that is capable of walking, eating meat, and [whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)**

That doesn't sound good. What does being a mammal have to do with the Java Runtime Environment and its threads? Should mammals know they are models running in a computer?  The answer, from the object-oriented modeling perspective, is clear: *mammals have nothing to do with JRE threads and should not implement the interface Runnable*.

Comment: Instead of implementing Runnable on Mammal, allowing the Run method to access its "guts", you must create and inner class in Mammal (e.g. MammalThread) that extends Runnable and has a clear and defined responsibility to provide an implementation feature to allow Mamal to run on its own Thread. This way, the required coupling for thread running is made explicit.